# SQL COUNT GROUP BY

Tags: sql, count, group-by

i have this table:

Code  Packet Weight
-------------------
11        2      20
12         1        45
11         1         15
12        4        15

how can i get the result:

Code  Packet Weight
-------------------
11        3      35
12         5        60

Thanks you in advance,
Stev

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT    Code,
          SUM(Packet) AS Packet,
          SUM([Weight]) AS [Weight]
FROM      [YourTable]
GROUP BY  CODE
ORDER BY  CODE
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Code, SUM(Packet) [Packet], SUM(Weight) [Weight]
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Code
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Code, SUM(Packet) as Packet, SUM(Weight) as Weight
FROM Table
GROUP BY Code
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select code, sum(packet), avg(weight) from mytable group by code
```

Comment: Not looking for average weight, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Packet) AS PacketSum,
    SUM(Weight) AS WeightSum

FROM table
GROUP BY Code
```

Comment: I think you mean `SUM(Weight) AS WeightSum` instead of `AVG` :)

Comment: Uhum, ****cough****, missed that one. Thanks! :D